# sumifs function in python

Tags: python, function, sumifs

I have a list of lists that looks like:

```
[['chr1', '3088', '1', 744, 'L1MCc_dup1']
['chr1', '3089', '1', 744, 'L1MCc_dup1']
['chr1', '3090', '1', 744, 'L1MCc_dup1']
['chr1', '15037', '1', 96, 'MER63B']
['chr1', '15038', '1', 96, 'MER63B']
['chr1', '15039', '1', 96, 'MER63B']
['chr1', '15040', '1', 96, 'MER63B']
['chr1', '19465', '1', 418, 'MLT2B4_dup1']
['chr1', '19466', '1', 418, 'MLT2B4_dup1']
['chr1', '19467', '1', 418, 'MLT2B4_dup1']]
```

I need to make the equivalent of a `sumifs` function in python (as the file is too big for excel) to sum the contents of column 3 based on the identifier in column 5 (output can be some version of `L1MCc_dup1` is 3, `MER63B` is 4 and `MLT2B4_dup1` is 3).

Any advice/help to make this function?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - SO is not a place to get someone else to write your code for you. What have you tried, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for row in my_list:
    key = row[4]
    value = int(row[2])
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + value
```

After this loop, `d` will map the key values in the last column to the desired sums.

You could also use `collections.defaultdict` instead of a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d =[['chr1', '3088', '1', 744, 'L1MCc_dup1'],
['chr1', '3089', '1', 744, 'L1MCc_dup1'],
['chr1', '3090', '1', 744, 'L1MCc_dup1'],
['chr1', '15037', '1', 96, 'MER63B'],
['chr1', '15038', '1', 96, 'MER63B'],
['chr1', '15039', '1', 96, 'MER63B'],
['chr1', '15040', '1', 96, 'MER63B'],
['chr1', '19465', '1', 418, 'MLT2B4_dup1'],
['chr1', '19466', '1', 418, 'MLT2B4_dup1'],
['chr1', '19467', '1', 418, 'MLT2B4_dup1']]
>>> sum(map(lambda x: x[3], filter(lambda x: x[4] == 'MLT2B4_dup1', d)))
1254
```

Sum of all column 4 values (I assume you meant that because it was the only int column), where the last column equals to `'MLT2B4_dup1'`. You can change that to any other condition of course.