# python pandas countifs using multiple criteria AND multiple data frames

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formulas

Trying to create--in Python using multiple data frames--the equivalent of a countifs in Excel that would span multiple sheets.

I need a new column count of records on *another data frame* based on criteria from the **current data frame**.

See [Excel impression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjgeM.png) of what I want to do in python, also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fex5j.png).

My goal?

- Count exams on *students* data frame
- by Student ID
- with exam date >= enroll date
- with exam date <= detail date
- with exam grade >= 70

Basically the Excel equivalent would be...

> =COUNTIFS(Summary!$B$1:$B$11, ">="&Detail!B2, 
>                              Summary!$B$1:$B$11, "<="&Detail!C2, 
>                              Summary!$C$1:$C$11, ">="&70, 
>                              Summary!$A$1:$A$11, "="&Detail!A2)

...where Summary is the primary data frame and Detail is the secondary data frame where I want to count records.

Found these answers in my research:

- [sumifs function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035767/sumifs-function-in-python)
- [What is a good way to do countif in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python)
- [Python Pandas counting and summing specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions)

Not quite what I'm looking for, because they don't span multiple data frames. I was able to create a basic countifs for a **singular** data frame:

```
sum(1 for x in students['Student ID'] if x == 1)
sum(1 for x in exams['Exam Grade'] if x >= 70)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you'll want to do is set up two dataframes, say `df1` for the "exams passed" information and `df2` for the marks on each exam.

To get yourself started, you can read in your excel files like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('filename1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('filename2.xlsx')
```

Then for each row in `df1` you want to segment `df2` and get the length of the segmented dataframe.

First though you might want to make list of information for each row in df1, which could be done like this:

```
student_info = df1[['Student ID', 'Enrollment Date', 'Qualification Date']].values
```

Then you can iterate through the rows like this:

```
N_exams_passed = [] # Store counts for each student in a list

for s_id, s_enroll, s_qual in student_info:
    N_exams_passed.append(len(df2[(df2['Student ID']==s_id) &
                                  (df2['Exam Date']>=s_enroll) &
                                  (df2['Exam Date']<=s_qual) &
                                  (df2['Grade']>=70)])
                          )
```

Then add/replace the column in df1:

```
df1['Exams Passed'] = N_exams_passed
```

In order to compare the dates properly you will need to convert them to datetime objects in each pandas dataframe, and I will leave this up to you. Hint: you can use the `pd.to_datetime()` function.

Comment: it works, thank you. Never would have arrived at that. Steep learning curve compared to Excel.