# faster way to run countifs in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, correlated-subquery

I previously asked the question on how to do a countifs in python across multiple data frames, just like you can do countifs on separate worksheets in Excel. somebody gave me a very creative answer:

[python pandas countifs using multiple criteria AND multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290153/python-pandas-countifs-using-multiple-criteria-and-multiple-data-frames)

Thank you for that @AlexG--I tried it, and it worked superbly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

#import the data
students = pd.read_csv("Student Detail stump.csv")
exams = pd.read_csv("Exam Detail stump.csv")

#get data parameters
student_info = students[['Student Number', 'Enrollment Date', 'Detail Date']].values

#prepare an empty list to hold the results
N_exams_passed = []

#count records in data set according to parameters
for s_id, s_enroll, s_qual in student_info:
N_exams_passed.append(len(exams[(exams['Student Number']==s_id) &
                         (exams['Exam Grade Date']>=s_enroll) &
                         (exams['Exam Grade Date']<=s_qual) &
                         (exams['Exam Grade']>=70)])
                      )

#add the results to the original data set
students['Exams Passed'] = N_exams_passed
```

HOWEVER, it only worked effectively on small data sets. When I ran the data with 100,000s of rows, it wouldn't even be done overnight. It doesn't seem very pythonic.

The SQL way you can do this in seconds is to use a correlated subquery, like this:

```
SELECT
   s.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(e.[Exam Grade]) 
 FROM
     exams AS e 
 WHERE
    e.[Exam Grade] >= 65 
    AND e.[Student Number] = s.[Student Number] 
    AND e.[Exam Grade Date] >= s.[Enrollment Date] 
    AND e.[Exam Grade Date] <= s.[Detail Date]) 
    AS ExamsPassed
FROM 
    students AS s;
```

How do I reproduce such a correlated subquery in pandas or some other pythonic way?

Here are the data frames:

```
 #Students
 Student Number Enroll Date Detail Date
 1              1/1/2016    2/1/2016
 1              1/1/2016    3/1/2016
 2              2/1/2016    3/1/2016
 3              3/1/2016    4/1/2016

 #Exams
 Student Number Exam Date   Exam Grade
 1              1/1/2016    50
 1              1/15/2016   80
 1              1/28/2016   90
 1              2/5/2016    100
 1              3/5/2016    80
 1              4/5/2016    40
 2              2/2/2016    85
 2              2/3/2016    10
 2              2/4/2016    100
```

Final data frame should look like this, with a count of 'Passed Exams' at the end:

```
 #FinalResult
 Student Number Enroll Date Detail Date Passed Exams
 1              1/1/2016    2/1/2016    2
 1              1/1/2016    3/1/2016    3
 2              2/1/2016    3/1/2016    2
 3              3/1/2016    4/1/2016    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the structure of your dataframes correctly, I'd suggest merging the two dataframes and then performing the task on the merged data using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np

exams = exams.merge(students, on='Student Number', how='left')
exams['Passed'] = np.where(
    (exams['Exam Grade Date'] >= exams['Enrollment Date']) &
    (exams['Exam Grade Date'] <= exams['Detail Date']) &
    (exams['Grade'] >= 70),
    1, 0)

students = students.merge(
    exams.groupby(['Student Number', 'Detail Date'])['Passed'].sum().reset_index(),
    left_on=['Student Number', 'Detail Date'],
    right_on=['Student Number', 'Detail Date'],
    how='left')
students['Passed'] = students['Passed'].fillna(0).astype('int')
```

*Note: you'll need to make sure the date columns are properly stored as datetimes (you can use `pandas.to_datetime` to do this).*

`numpy.where` creates a new array where the values are one way (`1` in the example above) if the conditions you specify are met and another (`0`) if they aren't met.

The line `exams.groupby(['Student Number', 'Detail Date'])['Passed'].sum()` produces a series in which the index is `Student Number` and `Detail Date` and the values are the counts of passed exams corresponding to that `Student Number` and `Detail Date` combination.  The `reset_index()` makes it into a dataframe for merging.

Comment: That merge resulted in duplication, so the counts didn't come back correctly.

Comment: Does the first part (the conditional counting) work and just the merge fail?  I might not understand your dataframe structure correctly.  In what way does the merge look wrong?

Comment: The merged frame resulted in more rows than exams, so when you grouped it, you ended up with more exams in 'Passed' than there were exam records.

Comment: I think I've fixed the problem by adding `how='left'` to the merge arguments.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: No, the final result shows as 5, 5, 2 when adding that to the merge, but the actual count should be 2,4,2. The merge should be de-duplicated on 'Student Number' and 'Detail Date', and I can't figure that out.

Comment: Can you add a small sample of your data (with fake names, of course) that causes the error when you run it, so that I can run the same data and fix the issue?

Comment: I edited the original post, adding the relevant data frames. Fake data.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your sample data - Student Number 1 is repeated (how should we know which student to assign the results to?  Do they refer to different students or the same one?) and Student Number 3 has no exams in the exams table but in your desired output has passed 1.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're correct... fixed it. The students should be as it is. It is not meant to be a normalized listing, as it is unique on Student ID and Detail date.

Comment: Now your column names are different from your original example.  Also, it's more helpful if you post data that can be directly copied into a script.