# Python Pandas Dataframe Conditional Count with Datetime Comparison Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif, python-datetime

## Background

I have two dataframes.  The first one, `df_player_snapshot_master`, has snapshot data for individual poker players at different times in a tournament and looks like this:

```
    snapshotDateTime            playerID    deactivationRecord
0   2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995  1679613     False
1   2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995  2660567     False
2   2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995  2668394     False
3   2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995  2280604     False
4   2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995  2018271     False
```

The second dataframe, `df_tournament_summary_master`, summarizes this data at a tournament level by snapshot and looks like this:

```
    intervalStartDateTime       intervalEndDateTime         playersDeactivatedThisInterval
0   2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995  2021-05-06 09:28:38.605930  NaN
1   2021-05-06 09:28:38.605930  2021-05-06 09:28:47.860595  NaN
2   2021-05-06 09:28:47.860595  2021-05-06 09:28:57.187734  NaN
3   2021-05-06 09:28:57.187734  2021-05-06 09:29:07.187734  NaN
```

My goal is to populate `df_tournament_summary_master['playersDeactivatedThisInterval']` by counting the number of records in `df_player_snapshot_master` where `df_player_snapshot_master['snapshotDateTime']` equals `df_tournament_summary_master['intervalStartDateTime']` and `df_player_snapshot_master['deactivationRecord']` is `True`.  So essentially a COUNTIFS exercise between two dataframes with multiple conditions.

## What I've Tried

I translated the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290153/python-pandas-countifs-using-multiple-criteria-and-multiple-data-frames) to my situation which resulted in this code:

```
tournament_info = df_tournament_summary_master[['intervalStartDateTime']].values

deacs = []

for iSDT in tournament_info:
    deacs.append(len(df_player_snapshot_master[(df_player_snapshot_master['snapshotDateTime']==iSDT) &
                                  (df_player_snapshot_master['deactivationRecord']==True)])
                          )

df_tournament_summary_master['playersDeactivatedThisInterval'] = deacs
```

but it keeps throwing an error:

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (332,), (1,))
```

The post I modeled my code after does mention the need to convert to datetimes and that seems like it might be the issue, but when I check my types for both dataframes/series they all seem to be datetimes already:

```
In:
display(tournament_info)

Out:
array([['2021-05-06T09:28:24.987995000'],
       ['2021-05-06T09:28:38.605930000'],
       ['2021-05-06T09:28:47.860595000'],
       ['2021-05-06T09:28:57.187734000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In:
df_player_snapshot_master.dtypes

Out:
snapshotDateTime           datetime64[ns]
playerID                           object
deactivationRecord                   bool
dtype: object
```

Of course, I've looked at other posts that deal with filtering dataframes by comparing dates and they all seem to use different solutions than the `for` loop I'd like to use, so I'm not sure how to re-purpose and adapt their advice.

## Questions

1. What is causing the ValueError I'm getting?
2. How do I populate `df_tournament_summary_master['playersDeactivatedThisInterval']` with the conditional count using a date comparison condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by counting the `sum` of `deactivationRecord` after a `groupby` on `snapshotDateTime`, then merge the dataframes. The results of your sample data aren't that exciting, but it should work:

```
time_groups = df_player_snapshot_master.groupby('snapshotDateTime')['deactivationRecord'].sum()
df = pd.merge(df_tournament_summary_master, time_groups, how='left', left_on=['intervalStartDateTime'], right_on=['snapshotDateTime'])
df = df.drop(['playersDeactivatedThisInterval'], axis = 1).rename(columns={"deactivationRecord": "playersDeactivatedThisInterval"})
```

Result:

|  | intervalStartDateTime | intervalEndDateTime | playersDeactivatedThisInterval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-05-06 09:28:24.987995 | 2021-05-06 09:28:38.605930 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-05-06 09:28:38.605930 | 2021-05-06 09:28:47.860595 | nan |
| 2 | 2021-05-06 09:28:47.860595 | 2021-05-06 09:28:57.187734 | nan |
| 3 | 2021-05-06 09:28:57.187734 | 2021-05-06 09:29:07.187734 | nan |

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This does solve the problem.  I have other similar applications though where I'm conducting a conditional count but am unsure how this generalizes to one condition, three conditions, or when the conditions have non-Boolean data types.  That's why the `for` loop format in the link I referenced is so attractive.  Does this generalize easily to other similar scenarios?